# Object not found error in ajax and php

Tags: ajax

```
eventClick: function(event) {

alert(event.id);
        $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: '<code>http://localhost/projects/bootmetro-master/demos/delete_events.php</code>', 
    data: 'id=' + event.id,
    success: function(json) {
             alert("Updated Successfully");
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
             window.location.href='http://localhost:80/projects/bootmetro-master/demos/coecalendar.html';
    }
});
},
```

Comment: i am not able to go to the specified link.Its showing object not found error.But the link specified in the url is perfectly fine.

Comment: Remove `<code>` from url.

Answer (score 0):

```
url: '<code>http://localhost/projects/bootmetro-master/demos/delete_events.php</code>',
```

Why there are the balises `<code>` ?